# Is there a free stock query service?

Tags: investing, nasdaq

Is there a web-based stock query service that allow me to look up for Stocks that match certain criteria?

E.g. I want to find ALL stocks that are on 52-week high, with an Avg-daily volume greater than 1 million, and that cost between 5 and 10.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Almost every screener is able to do this. Please put effort into researching.

Take the difference between
http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=sh_avgvol_o1000,sh_price_u10,ta_highlow52w_nh&ft=4
and
http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=sh_avgvol_o1000,sh_price_u5,ta_highlow52w_nh&ft=4
to get your results.

Even MSN Money can do this http://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockscreener/52weekhighs